# OpenJPA says: You have supplied colums for FooBar but this mapping cannot have columns in this context

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have some Java entity classes that are working well in my production code. I am writing an automated test for this application where I am reusing the very same classes.

When the test application is creating its entity manager this way:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("provider", "org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl");
 props.setProperty(...);      
 EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("foobar-upgrade-restful-test", props);

 EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

The applications throws an error message telling that:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: You have supplied columns for "com.foo.bar.server.commontypes.job.CompositeJob", but this mapping cannot have columns in this context.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingInfo.assertNoSchemaComponents(MappingInfo.java:382)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.FlatClassStrategy.map(FlatClassStrategy.java:51)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.setStrategy(ClassMapping.java:392)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.RuntimeStrategyInstaller.installStrategy(RuntimeStrategyInstaller.java:56)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.prepareMapping(MappingRepository.java:411)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.preMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:762)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:651)
    ... 72 more
```

I do not really understand the error message as the same entity bean is working in the application under Glassfish and the persistence.xml is also almost identical. (In the test I use `RESOURCE_LOCAL` tx instead of JTA but I doubt that it has relation with this error.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You should provide the two XML mappings for this entity. Probably they are, like you said, almost identical and the issue is related to the mapping.

Comment: There are no xml mappings, I use annotation based config and so there is no difference.

Comment: Does your test environment (can you provide more details) support annotations for JPA? Are you listing your entities in the persistence.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that there is a problem with the mapping information that you provided for `com.foo.bar.server.commontypes.job.CompositeJob`.

I'm guessing the reason it works for JTA, but not resource local most likely has to do with some oddity in the way that metadata is loaded / processed in the different environments. It would be helpful if you post the relevant mapping data from your Entity.

Comment: Thanks @Rick. I had a quite a few issues like this recently. I checked for the following things: 1. Mapping is correct - onetoone, onetomany...., 2. The entity is right and has representation for all columns specified in the schema, 3. The table name is declared (yes, i did miss this one), 4. The entity is added to persistence.xml

Comment: @Alice - I'd suggest posting a question to the openjpa users mailing list with details on your Entities.

Comment: Thanks @Rick. I was able to resolve those issues. I got the same error as above. I added the checklist of things that helped me resolve the issues as these might help someone else as well. Thanks again.